# Firebase notifications security / console activity log

Tags: firebase, firebase-notifications, firebase-console

i'm thinking about using Firebase for the notification service that my app needs. However, its important that the process of sending notifications is secure. I want to avoid a notification being sent from any member of the team without permission.

One way could be assigning restricted roles and permissions for the team members. However it also would be good to have any kind of activity log in the console, or have a log of all notifications sent including the name of the user. The console currently allows you to see all notifications sent, but i cannot see who sent it, and also the notification can be deleted from the log.

Any ideas on how to manage this? Which specific roles would you recommend me to use? Is it possible with Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function in Firebase which sends notifications, and you have logs on that function. [Here is how to write a function which send notifications](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications)